# Install MAAS before I Install MAAS?

Tags: 14.04, maas, cloud

Maybe I'm not understanding how the setup exactly works, but every guide I find on how to initially set up MAAS (in order to use juju and ubuntu to create a cloud environment) there is a step for me to add an Ubuntu MAAS API address.  How would I already have a MAAS API address if this is my first time setting up anything with MAAS?  It's obvious to me that I'm not understanding something about the configuration.  Can anyone clear this up for me?

Also, I feel like I understand the basics of how MAAS and juju work together, so please don't just link to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure , because I've read that pretty thoroughly.  I just need to know what this whole MASS API is about for a first time installer who's never setup anything related to MAAS before.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you install is the region-controller/cluster-controller. You have to tell the controller the address it should give to the nodes to tell them how to reach the cluster-controller.

So in many (simple) cases the address will just be the address of the server you are setting up right now.

Answer (score 1):

MAAS API is two things, first and what I use the most is a webpage.  The MAAS API address is the ip address of the computer the MAAS regional controller is on.  This webpage allows you to allocate nodes to different users, setup networking, and for the most part configure MAAS settings to make it work correctly.

Install MAAS can be done in one of two ways.  When Ubuntu is installed, select the "Multiple server install with MAAS".  This is the second or third screen into the install, after it asks which language to select.

The second is just to install.

```
sudo apt-get install maas
```

If you use this command you will also need to run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller

sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
```

These will ask you for the ip address of your maas server.  If you change the ipaddress of your MAAS server you will need to run these commands again.

The MAAS API is also a set of command line tools too.  Everything you can do with the webpage you can do with a command line tool and a lot more.  I personally don't use the command line tools because it is easy to mess things up and not be able to see exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to login to the API for commandline access, you can create a user 'profile'. This effectively authorises the running user access to the API

Have you checked out the actual MAAS documentaion? There is a section on this with screenshots and everything.

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/maascli.html#api-key

Basically, you need to login to the MAAS server web interface to access the key which is autogenerated when you install MAAS.